# How do I change dev tools console scope to be local to a function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

How do I use Chrome dev tools to evaluate code within the local scope of a function? I.e. for the following code

```
const name1 ="alireza"

function person(){
    const name2 ="joe" 
}
```

the result of code manually executed in the console should be

```
console.log(name2) //"joe"
```

Comment: the function is here only to display scope.  I want to find a way to write `console.log()` on inside of the function in the chrome dev tool.

Comment: I don't want to change the javascript, you can imagine like this I don't have access to the javascript file and I'm using the chrome dev tool in order to access it. and now I want to log the name 2 in order to see what is its value but currently, I can only log name 1 with the chrome dev tool.

Comment: the function is only here to display **scope** .don't play around the function I already know how to use function you can reproduce it this way: simply create a js file with the code above and then open it in the browser after that go to console section in dev tools and write  console.log(name1) you will get "alireza" so the question is this how to do something like console.log(name2) and get "joe" back and don't tell me that you cant because of scope. yes, you are right! but what if I move the console.log to the inside of  function? how to change dev tools console scope to be local?

Comment: you misunderstood what  I said I mean I want to solve this only with the chrome dev tool and I give the example to you only to show you the environment. I don't want you to **fix the code** I want you to find a way to grab the data in name2 with the chrome dev tool.

Comment: Are you asking how to control the scope in which code entered in the Dev Tools Console tab will be executed?

Comment: yes, @Quentin
  you get what I talking about! I want to be able to use the dev tool console tab inside the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for are [breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/):

You can dynamically [set a breakpoint on a line](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#loc) within the function you want to inspect: devTools will break before the execution of that line and you can evaluate code within the scope of that function in the console.

Alternatively - if you can change the code (which you can also [from devTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/sources/#edit)) - you can put a [`debugger` statement](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#debugger) where you want the execution to break.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly tricky because the statement you want to examine is the only statement in the function.

If you were to add another statement on the following line:

```
const name1 ="alireza"

function person(){
    const name2 ="joe" 
    const name3 ="bob";
}
```

Then you could:

1. Open the Debugger tab
2. Create a break point on the line after `const name2 ="joe"`
3. Open the Console tab
4. Type `person()` to run the `person` function
5. Wait for the breakpoint to be hit
6. Return to the Console tab
7. Type `console.log(name2);` (or you could just look at the debugging information in the Debugging tab which reports all the in-scope variables).